# Laying out a stack of clickable playing cards in Android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm writing a card-melding game for Android. I display the player's current unmelded cards in a series of ImageViews in one FrameLayout and the melded cards below in another FrameLayout. I offset each card from the previous one.

I can lay the cards out starting from the left-hand-side of the screen relatively easily. But I would prefer to have them centered. Here are the problems:

- If I use layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_gravity="center_horizontal", FrameLayout clips the resulting ImageView stack based on the largest single ImageView (this is documented).
- If I use layout_width="match_parent" and layout_gravity="left", (as in the code below), the melds look fine except they are not centered
- Strangely, even though I set layout_gravity="left", the first ImageView is being positioned centered horizontally.

I have programmatically adjusted the TranslationX to do the centering as in the code snippet. But this involves some trial-and-error and seems hackish.

Questions:

1. Any suggestions for a better way to do all this? (btw, I started with LayeredDrawable but switched once I understood that the individual drawables would not be clickable).
2. Am I misunderstanding the role of layout_gravity? I thought it applied to the child Views, but it seems to have no effect.

Layout snippet (the relevant blocks are the two FrameLayouts):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/Play"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/score_and_game"
    android:id="@+id/play_area"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game_info_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/blank"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/current_cards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/current_melds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        >
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Code snippet for hacking the positioning:

```
static final float CARD_OFFSET =30.0f;
static final float ADDITIONAL_MELD_OFFSET = 20.0f;
static final float CARD_WIDTH = 72.0f;
....
//show melds and unmelded as ImageViews
private void showCards(ArrayList<CardList> meldLists, FrameLayout frameLayout) {
    ArrayList<ImageView> cardLayers = new ArrayList<>(Game.MAX_CARDS);
    float xOffset=0f;
    frameLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (CardList cardlist : meldLists) {
        for (Card card : cardlist.getCards()) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageDrawable(card.getDrawable());
            iv.setTranslationX(xOffset);
            iv.bringToFront();
            cardLayers.add(iv);
            xOffset += CARD_OFFSET;
        }
        xOffset += ADDITIONAL_MELD_OFFSET;
    }
    //bit of a hack: we now adjust everything by - 1/2*(width of stacked image) to center it
    // add CARD_WIDTH because the total width of the stacked image is sum(offsets) + CARD_WIDTH
    // subtract CARD_OFFSET and ADDITIONAL_MELD_OFFSET because we added these at the end of the loop (but they're not in the layout)
    xOffset = xOffset - CARD_OFFSET - ADDITIONAL_MELD_OFFSET + CARD_WIDTH;
    if (!cardLayers.isEmpty()) {
        for (ImageView iv : cardLayers) {
            iv.setTranslationX(iv.getTranslationX()-0.5f*xOffset);
            frameLayout.addView(iv);
        }
    }
}//end showCards
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to RelativeLayout with these layout params:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/current_cards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:gravity="center">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/current_melds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:gravity="center">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and with essentially the same code, and this works as expected. It also allows clicking on individual cards as dscribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592976/clickable-area-of-stacked-views-in-framelayout-not-correct-relativelayout-works)